# Is it suspicious for a conference abstract submission to be subordinated to registration?

Tags: conference, fees, abstract

My PhD advisor and I wish to participate to a specific international conference in our field.

The program seems legitimate and part of the scientific committee are respected researchers of my field, with whom we have already worked in the past. Therefore I am not questioning the academic relevancy of the conference.

On the other hand, the organization is operated by a company, and I am not at ease with their methods. Mainly, the registration fee (500€) must be paid before submitting any abstract and it is not possible to know whether the abstract has been accepted before committing.

Beside the frustration (a conference is a big investment in our budget), I find this unusual, if not fishy. This is the first time my advisor is confronted with the situation, and they are conflicted about this too.

As a side point, their privacy policy includes an agreement to transmit my academic information to "marketing partners", which I am not at ease either.

Should I be worried?

**EDIT** after investigating a bit more. The organizer is not exactly a company, but a "non-profit private organisation".

**UPDATE** after contacting the organizers. The website actually gives the option to pay later, as long as the registration is placed. Ultimately, the admission decision will be issued before the payment deadline, although that was not apparent unless you create an account and place the order first.

Comment: Have you asked the members of the scientific committee about the conference? Perhaps they can explain the reasoning behind the registration fee (and confirm whether or not the conference is legit).

Comment: I would be worried.

Comment: I would not call it suspicious, just different. Possibly is a hybrid between a conference and a sort of fair/exhibition in which industry is present for business and not only research? We were in one of this type and we were there for kind of "political" reasons.

Comment: @Emma good suggestion, I will ask my advisor to do that since he knows them better.

Comment: Maybe it's a predatory conference! https://www.exordo.com/blog/9-signs-this-is-a-fake-conference/

Comment: A list of questionable conferences : https://libguides.caltech.edu/c.php?g=512665&p=3503029 . Check the conference title here!

Comment: @Eilia neither the conference nor the organizer are listed there. Yet the event has taken place a number of times over the years.

Comment: Things like the IEEE and APS (American Physical Society) are also private incorporated organizations and hold completely legitimate conferences. If the conference has been ongoing for some time, and is known in the field, and attracts people you know year after year, then it is likely just fine. Why do you want to go to this conference in particular?

Comment: @JonCuster the topic and speakers are highly relevant to my research, and we are seeking to convince others to adopt a methodology I developped

Comment: OK, so do you know those speakers? Have they attended the conference in the past? If so, ask them about the conference and how it all works.

Answer (score 7):

€500 is within the normal range for an international conference, but the mandatory subscription before getting the notification of acceptance is indeed a bit suspicious.

However there are some conferences which work in the following way: pretty much any abstract submitted is accepted (except if out of scope, I guess) and is supposed to be presented at the conference. The selection process happens when a subset of the abstracts are accepted for publication as a full paper in a journal issue. I'm not very familiar with this setting myself, but I assume that it might make sense for such a conference to make sure that the authors attend and present their work even if it's not selected for the journal issue.

Comment: Interesting. I should say at this point that the conference's website does not mention any such selection process.

Comment: @Alexis I'd say it's worth sending an email to the organizers about this peculiar setting, simply asking them the reason why registration is mandatory this early in the process and whether they would reimburse the fee in case your abstract is rejected.